# Statistics on correlation between reputation / answer quality?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I'm wondering if anyone has performed any statistics on correlation between highest-voted answers (regardless of time of post) and poster's current reputation.

Specifically, I'd like to somehow answer the question: Can statistics back up my gut feeling that high-rep users were "good" even without much "practice"?

Or, put another way, is reputation not only a good way of measuring the time and effort put into answering, but also one's "true skill" in the area in general?

Comment: Sounds like an interesting correlation to research. I'm looking for pointers to the SO API for a similar query.

Comment: If you get something like this written, e.g. using http://stackapps.com/questions/198/py-stackexchange-an-api-wrapper-for-python, please post it. I'd like to use it as a template for checking other correlations.